# C# Check if data exists in List View Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want to do is actually getting a set of data then group it by the identifier, something like this:

123456
123456
456789
456789
456789
135790

to

```
Name       Quantity
123456        2
456789        3 
135790        1
```

What I've done so far:

```
Foreach(string name in itemlist) //itemlist = 123456,123456... as mentioned above
{
  var listitems= lvTest.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>;
  bool exists = listitems.Where(item => item.Text == name).Any(); // to check if item name is already exists in list view
  if (!exists)
  {
        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { name, "1" });
        lvTest.Items.Add(lvItem);
   }
        else
   {
        ListViewItem lvItem = lvTest.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>.Where(item => item.Text == name).FirstOrDefault();
        int count = (int)lvItem.SubItems[1].Text;
        count = count + 1;
        lvItem.SubItems[1].Text = count.ToString();
   }
}
```

But this won't work due to the issue "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable" in the line of

```
var listitems= lvTest.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable in asp.net,linq,c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290325/cannot-assign-method-group-to-an-implicitly-typed-local-variable-in-asp-net-linq)

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, end up the issue is because I did not put bracket after Cast function. It should be

```
var listitems= lvTest.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
```

Comment: Isn't C# fun? :D

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use something like this,

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string> { "123456", "123456", "456789", "456789", "456789", "135790" };

var lstGroupList = lstString .GroupBy(item => item,
              (key, group) => new { key, Items = group.ToList()}).ToList();
```